# Php Unit Testing: How do i access find() and get() in testController

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I can access find() and get() in the tableTest.php but can't access it in the ControllerTest.php. How do i gain access in cakephp3?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us the code that's not working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by using TableRegistry::get(TableName) in the setUp() function